# How to sign an Oauth 1.0 request that includes files

Tags: oauth

What's the proper process to follow when signing an Oauth 1.0 request that includes files?  Do you include the file for the hash calculation or just some key of it?  Or is it omitted entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to include parameters in the signature base string with a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Your file upload is going to be `multipart/form-data` so you don't need to include any part of the file for the signature calculation. See [here](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor13) for more information.